# What template system uses <?r ... ?>

Tags: ruby, templates

I saw [this strange looking template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ioquatix/latinum/master/README.md) code, and want to know which templating system it belongs to:

```
        <?r currencies.each do |currency| ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">#{currency} Summary:</td>
            <td class="total">#{f.text summary[:total][currency]}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?r end ?>
```

The inline language is certainly Ruby, but `<?r ... ?>` is not ERB's `<% ... %>` that I am familiar with.

Comment: Can you link to where you saw this?

Comment: @JohnFeminella just added now, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ioquatix/trenni

Comment: Yeah, it's the gem author's own template engine. He even created a linter for it: `'begin': '(^\\s+)?<\\?r(?!>)'`
https://github.com/ioquatix/language-trenni/blob/master/grammars/trenni.cson

Comment: I was just [searching ioquatix's repositories for "template"](https://github.com/ioquatix?tab=repositories&q=template) and Trenni was the first (and only) hit :-)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! I originally searched on http://symbolhound.com/ but it was not indexed there :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code's author, Samuel Williams also created a templating system called [Trenni](https://github.com/ioquatix/trenni) which uses the syntax:

```
<?r expression ?>
```

to evaluate the given expression in Ruby.

According to Trenni's [README](https://github.com/ioquatix/trenni#motivation), it was influenced / inspired by the template engines [ezamar](https://github.com/manveru/ezamar) and [nagoro](https://github.com/manveru/nagoro) by Michael Fellinger.